# Can we say that for $t\in [p,q]$, $f(t)\in [f(p),f(q)]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: I \to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function where $I$ is any interval. Now suppose there is a compact interval $I_1 \subset f(I)$, then we can express it as $I_1=[f(p),f(q)]$ where $p,q\in I$. Let $p<q$, then can we say that for $t\in [p,q]$, $f(t)\in I_1$ ?

By IVT, for every $f(a)\in I_1$, there is an element $b\in [p,q]$ such that $f(b)=f(a)$, but I don't think we can have that $f([p,q])\subset I_1$? Right?

Comment: maybe the original question is there “exists” $p$ and $q$ ？

Answer (score 2):

you are right. consider $f(x)=-x(x-4)$. let $[p, q]=[0,3]$, $t=2$